# Replace first two characters with three characters SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, string, oracle, replace

I have a question

I want to join two tables (Table1 and Table2) on custID column.

However for the join to work I need to edit Table1s custID column vlaues by removing the first two characters ('CC') and replacing them with 0s so the final output is padded to 8 digits.

So if Table1 had a value in custID of CC34054 then this would need to be converted to 00034054 for the join to identify that value in Table2.custID. If for instance the custID value in Table1 was CC3356, the value would need to be revised to 00003356 for the join to match.

Ive made some tables below so I can illustrate what I mean.

Table1

| CustID |
| --- |
| CC34054 |
| CC3356 |
| CC87901 |

Table2

| CustID |
| --- |
| 00034054 |
| 00003356 |
| 00087901 |

I hope this makes sense. thanks!

Comment: Checkout https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_replace.php

Comment: If `CC` is always present at the left, then you may use `lpad(substr(col, 3), 8, '0')` for one table or `'CC' || ltrim(col, '0')` for another depending on the cardinality and/or indexes

Answer (score 0):

One option is to replace `CC` with an empty string and apply `LPAD` function to fill up to 8 characters with zeros; do it either in `JOIN` or - possibly - by updating `table1` (so join would then look simpler, just `on a.custid = b.custid`).

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  table1 (custid, name) as
  3    (select 'CC34054', 'Little' from dual union all
  4     select 'CC3356' , 'Scott'  from dual
  5    ),
  6  table2 (custid, surname) as
  7    (select '00034054', 'Foot'  from dual union all
  8     select '00003356', 'Tiger' from dual
  9    )
```

Query:

```
 10  select b.custid, a.name, b.surname
 11  from table1 a join table2 b on
 12    lpad(replace(a.custid, 'CC', ''), 8, '0') = b.custid;

CUSTID   NAME   SURNAME
-------- ------ ----------
00034054 Little Foot
00003356 Scott  Tiger

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to use SubStr() function to remove the first two characters (either they are 'CC' or anything else) and then do the Lpad to the length of 8 with '0' characters:

```sql
Select b.CUSTID
From tbl_1 a 
Inner Join tbl_2 b on (Lpad(SubStr(a.CUSTID, 3), 8, '0') = b.CUSTID)
```

Regards...

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to replace or pad leading characters, rather trim for both `CustID` columns if the data model is fixed throughout the whole table such as

```
SELECT *
  FROM Table1 t1
  JOIN Table2 t2
    ON LTRIM(t1.CustID,'C') = LTRIM(t2.CustID,'0')
```

in which using only single characters as the second arguments would be sufficient.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/VNXYOZqK)</kbd>